# Set the fetch size with Spring Data

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-jpa

For large result sets, it’s important to increase the fetch size. There have been numerous discussions on how to set the fetch size for Spring’s `JdbcTemplate`. However, we usually use Spring Data for database access. How can I set the fetch size for a Spring Data query, assuming we use JPA with Hibernate as provider?

Comment: How to set the fetch-size depends on which underlying technology one used (jdbc, jpa etc.) and for JPA which implementor (Hibernate, OpenJPA ec.).

Comment: I had added the `spring-data-jpa` tag already, but now edited my question to be more explicit about this.

Comment: Have you already read [the hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html)? This basically has nothing to with Spring Data JPA, but all with configuring the underlying container.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It depends on what you want to set. If you want it globally simply add it as a property to your persistence.xml (or what your way of configuration the `EntityManagerFactory` is). For hibernate that means adding the `hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size` property.

```
<property name="hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size" value="50" />
```

If you want to specify it for certain queries use query hints from JPA on the Query object.

```
TypedQuery<Foo> q = em.createTypedQuery("some hql here", Foo.class);
q.setHint("org.hibernate.fetchSize", "100");
```

Or when using Spring Data JPA use a `@QueryHints` annotation on the interface method. Can be applied to both methods with and without `@Query`.

```
@QueryHints(@javax.persistence.QueryHint(name="org.hibernate.fetchSize", value="50"))
List<Foo> findAll();
```

Links

1. Hibernate [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-hibernatejdbc)
2. Spring Data JPA [reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-hints) | [javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/QueryHints.html)
3. JPA 2 Query Hints [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/QueryHint.html)
4. [List of query hints](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/entitymanager/reference/en/html/objectstate.html#d0e1215) for Hibernate

Comment: Accepted your answer, as it works. But isn’t it extremely weird that for JPA (and Spring Data) I have to use a provider-specific configuration while in JDBC it’s a simple call on the Statement?

Comment: JPA is all about abstracting away JDBC and as there isn't a standard hint for the fetchsize (yet) you will have to use the provider specific ones. Maybe in a newer JPA version they will add these things.

Comment: wouldn't returning a list mean it queries all of the objects?

Comment: to set it globally in `appplication.properties`, use: `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size=100`